# In Android 12 on my Galaxy S10+, without PC, how to use "toybox"

Tags: toybox

I know that Android internally uses Toybox as its basics for Linux sh commands. And in Internet I can read about toybox the help doc.

==

Presumably since I do not want to have connection to a computer, there is no possibility in Samsung Galaxy S10+, Android 12, to use ADB.

Am I right?

==

Thus, in my smartphone by itself, how can I invoke toybox and use toybox its shell commands.

This, please, as a general question.

==

Now especially, this I want to do while programming a Button in Total Commander.

E.g. as a first test, I wrote in the Button "toybox --version". This works.

==

Then ongoing I want how to use the sh copy command "cp" (exhausting all options).

==

Then how to use shell variables. In toybox there seems not to exist Parameter Expansion with "$variablename". How is the usage of variables in toybox, thus in Android?

I mean general shell variables, beside the parameters defined for the Buttons, e.g. %P, %T, %M, %N, ...

==

In Internet there is no article about these items.

If needfull, I am willing to learn Java, and have already bought a thick book. Is there a intraductory documentation regarding these itens.

==

For other purposes I use Termux. But Termux has no direct access to the files and variables  as I need in in Total Commander Buttons.

Thanks, Regards

Comment: As you wrote toy box is just a set of tools. If you would want it you could use those tools via Termux, then of course with permissions of Termux. So the real problem is not the toy box tools but the permissions you need to do so. Sk you should better edit your question and describe what you are trying to do instead of focusing on tools that won't help you unless you have the correct permissions.

Comment: "*using toybox*" the title seems too broad, but it seems your main question is "How to store and use shell variables in an app that can execute shell commands"? (Not an expert, just trying to scope the question better)